# How to do a single handler for array of inputs in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, input, handler

I know how to make multiple handlers for multiple input fields but I would like to create just one handler working for dynamic number of input fields and I got stuck. I am unable to modify the inputs and they have fixed value.

This is the state of the main component

```
this.state = {
assetAccounts:["Cash","Financial Investment","Real Estate","Private Business Value"],
accounts:[0,1,2,3]
}
this.onChangeAccount = this.onChangeAccount.bind(this)
```

This is the handler

```
    onChangeAccount = (e,index) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let data = this.state.accounts;
    data[index]=value;
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({
        accounts: [...data]
    })
}
```

and this is rendered:

```
<table>
{this.state.assetAccounts.map((account,index)=>(<Account value={this.state.accounts[index]} name={account} key={index} onChange={this.onChangeAccount.bind(this)}/>))}
</table>
```

Account is my own component:

```
import React from 'react';
class Account extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <tr>     
            <td width="200px">{this.props.name}</td>
            <td>    
            <input
                type="text" value={this.props.value}
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
            />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </div>           
        );
    }
}    
export default Account;
```

If anyone knows how to make each of the individual accounts possible to edit separately, I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prop `onChange` of component `Account` only accept one paramater `e`.
You should pass parameter `index` when use `Account`.
Just do like this:

```
<table>
{this.state.assetAccounts.map((account,index)=>(<Account value={this.state.accounts[index]} name={account} key={index} onChange={e => this.onChangeAccount(e, index)}/>))}
</table>
```

Actually, pass `e.target.value` as a parameter for `onChange` in `Account` instead of `e` is better.